# Django Markdownx Trouble

Tags: python, django, markdown, django-markdownx

I am having trouble with markdown on my Django application. I am writing a blog from a tutorial, and want markdown in my posts. I installed [Markdownx](https://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/) for Django, and it almost works.

I have issues when it comes to code blocks. The markdown looks different in the admin page than it does in the rendering of the html page. I would like my code blocks to appear as they do on stackoverflow and github. Instead, when I do the code block formatting with the three ```, I get red text.

Below are my files for the application I am asking about:

`project/urls.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('projects/', include('projects.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

`project/settings.py`

```py
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'projects',
    'blog',
    'markdownx',
]
...
```

`app/models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from markdownx.models import MarkdownxField
from markdownx.utils import markdownify

class Projects(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    short_description = models.TextField()
    long_description = MarkdownxField()
    project_link = models.URLField(max_length=250)

    def formatted_markdown(self):
        return markdownify(self.long_description)
```

`app/admin.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from projects.models import Projects
from markdownx.admin import MarkdownxModelAdmin

class ProjectsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Projects, MarkdownxModelAdmin)
```

`app/views.py`

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from projects.models import Projects

def project_index(request):
    projects = Projects.objects.all()
    context = {
        'projects' : projects
    }
    return render(request, 'project_index.html', context)

def project_detail(request, pk):
    project = Projects.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {
        'project' : project
    }
    return render(request, 'project_detail.html', context)
```

`app/templates/project_detail.html`

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block page_content %}
<h1>{{ project.title }}</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h5>About the project:</h5>
        <p>{{ project.formatted_markdown|safe|linebreaks }}</p>
        <br>
        <h5>Project Link</h5>
        <a href="{{  project.project_link }}" class="btn btn-primary" >Github</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**This first image is the admin page view.**

[image: Admin page view]

---

**This second image is the template html page view.**
[image: Template page view]

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the correct Markdown extensions and possibly supply some CSS.

As a reminder, fenced code blocks (blocks deliminated with triple backticks ```` ``` ````) are a non-standard feature. According to the documentation, Markdownx uses Python-Markdown to parse the Markdown text and Python-Markdown only supports the standard Markdown features by default (as defined [here](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)). Therefore, you need to enable the [`fenced_code`](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/fenced_code_blocks/) extension to properly parser fenced code blocks.

You will also need to enable the [`codehilite`](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/code_hilite/) extension if you want your codeblocks to be highlighted. You will also need to install the `pygments` package which `codehilite` uses. You will also need to provide the CSS to define the styles (colors) for the highlighted code. GitHub user richeland has provided a number of different [CSS style sheets](https://github.com/richleland/pygments-css) which work with Pygments along with a preview of each theme.

According to the documentation, Markdownx has a [MARKDOWNX_MARKDOWN_EXTENSIONS](https://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/customization/#markdownx_markdown_extensions) setting for enabling extensions. Therefore you may need to add the following to your `settings.py` file:

```py
MARKDOWNX_MARKDOWN_EXTENSIONS = ['fenced_code', 'codehilite']
```

To install pygments run the following command:

```
pip install pygments
```

Then after selecting the highlighting theme you prefer, copy the appropriate CSS to your files and include a link to it in your templates.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it definitely helped! Although, it still doesn't work. I looked into the documentation a little further and it seems some of the documentation sites are offline. I managed to find that `MARKDOWNX_MARKDOWN_EXTENSIONS = ['markdown.extensions.codehilite']` looks like that instead. Still that didn't work, though. I installed pygments, but not sure where to place the css files, so I placed them in my static directory. I will look into this further and try different things. You have guided me in a direction and I appreciate it!

Comment: Did you add links to the CSS files in your page templates? The CSS won't do anything if you don't link to it.

Comment: Note that while not wrong, `markdown.extensions.codehilite` is an older, deprecated way to enable an extension. With newer versions of Markdown `codehilite` will work just fine.

Comment: This is kind of embarrassing, but I don't know if I'm adding the CSS files correctly. Here is how I inlcuded the chosen css file from that link you gave me: `<link href="{% static 'defualt.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`. This line is in my applications template, which is what I show in my post. I also have my static directory in my projects root, which has the `default.css` stylesheet in it. I've been trying to look online for possible solutions to this, and I see a ton of older documentation, but no newer documentation.

Comment: That looks right to me, but then I haven't used Django in years so I can't comment on the `{% static %}` thing. To ensure everything is correct, fire up the dev server, load a page in our browser and use the browser's dev tools to confirm that the file is properly referenced and that the rules are being applied to a code block.